# How make reference to background-image?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am making a webpage and I want to apply a Blur filter to my body background-image property, to do that I need to make reference to the background-image property, Is that possible?

Comment: Not clear, can you paste the code so far you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use two different div, one for the background image and the other for the data you will be inserting.

See the example below where I have created two div -

1. .background
2. .data

Both of them are placed with `position: fixed` and `left: 0; right: 0;`. The difference in displaying them comes from the `z-index` values which have been set differently for the elements.

**HTML**

```
<div class="background-image"></div>
<div class="content">
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <p>New Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.background-image {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;

  display: block;
  background-image: url('https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2015/mf-husains-100th-birthday-5102553322749952.2-hp.jpg');
  width: 1200px;
  height: 800px;

  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.content {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```